# How do I get the numeric component of a Date object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, date

I have a JSON Object that when stringified looks like this `[{"x":"/Date(1451606400000)/","y":877282.57}]`

and I want to get the numeric part of the date `1451606400000`

I can use regex, but is there an easier way involving parsing the date object? Perhaps I can construct a date from that value and then call a method to get the numeric component?

Comment: If you have a `Date` object, why not just call `getTime()`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, but once you have a date as an instance of [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), you can do `date.valueOf()` or `Number(date)` or even `+date` to get numeric timestamp, like in `+new Date()`.

Comment: "I have a date object" — Do you? Really? Or do you have a **string** with ASP.NET's idea of a JSON representation of a date in it? Or so you have exactly what you put in the question … which is a *regular expression literal*? Try providing a real [mcve].

Comment: Now, the opposite way, if you have a number that represents a timestamp, you can simply pass it as the first argument of Date constructor, like `new Date(date)`. The question is really unclear, sorry.

Comment: You could be right, I have expanded my answer. I assumed it was a date object but in order to ask the question I had to stringify it to try and see what I had. I assumed it was a date object. I'm still not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite confusing.
When you say "I want to get the numeric part" I don't get it.. maybe you can be more explicit.

My anwser assummes you want to convert a string value to date object (again I might be wrong)

```
var dateString = "1451606400000"; //save string value to a varable
var dateInt = Number(dateString); //convert to number

//after converting to number parse the value into the date object.
//Note: parsing a string value direct will through an exception
var dateObject = new Date(dateInt);
console.log(dateObject); //Date 2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: I thought I was explicit, I have `[{"x":"/Date(1451606400000)/","y":877282.57}]` and I want `1451606400000`. However I have solved it now using regex `x.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1)`. I thought it might be possible to do say, `y = new Date(x)` and then `y.toNumber()` or something but it doesn't look like it.

Comment: oops! I posted this anwser before the update

Comment: no worries my original post I was quite confused about what I was seeing ;)

Comment: try parseInt() then. e.g  parseInt('/Date(1451606400000)/', replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''), 10)